# Redirecting HTTP and HTTPS from LAN to a page with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables

I'm using the `iptables` command on a router running Bananian Linux in order to redirect all incoming traffic to a small webserver which serves a 302 Redirect to a login page (also hosted on the router). Due to how I'm using the router, I can't just serve the login page - I need to redirect to it.

The commands I've used to do this so far are:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i br0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.9.2:8000 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This works well in most cases - except HTTPS pages. HTTP pages go to the login page, where HTTPS pages get a Connection Closed error.

How can I make `iptables` redirect HTTPS to the correct page?

Comment: Is your router listening for https connections on any port?

Comment: Not specifically. It is just kind of listening to everything at the moment, and trying to do all of it with HTTP. I might need to change that.

Comment: If the client is attempting an https session, NATting it to a port listening for http sessions will not work, it needs to nat to something expecting https.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a secure server that can complete the SSL handshake and serve the 302 Redirect. Users will still get a certificate error (since they aren't reaching the server they asked for), which they'll have to click through.